# C++ how load the .NET runtime and thereby host WPF components

Tags: c++, wpf, visual-studio

[The Visual Studio devenv.exe executable is a native program. However, native programs can load the .NET runtime and thereby host Windows Forms and WPF components.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2679986/5306861)

I want to do as Visual Studio How to do it?

Comment: Visual Studio's extension model is heavily COM based.  COM is one of the standard techniques to execute managed code from an unmanaged program.  Custom-hosting the CLR is another.

Comment: @HansPassant: While much of the legacy VS extensibility is provided via COM, much of the newer extensibility mechanisms are managed (e.g. via the [Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx) and/or [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) etc,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog post from Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/07/09/use-clr4-hosting-api-to-invoke-net-assembly-from-native-c.aspx) and its [associated tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0) demonstrate how to use the new CLR hosting API's to host the CLR within your native apps.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416471/CLR-Hosting-Customizing-the-CLR) article also illustrates how to use the new CLR4 hosting API's.

As OP requested: [Here's the first article of a series](http://daniel-albuschat.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-net-and-wpf-in-win32-legacy.html) exploring how to host the CLR & WPF in a native app.

Also, [here's an article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/nfc/article.php/c14589/Hosting-WPF-Content-in-an-MFC-Application.htm) about how to host a WPF control within an VC++/MFC app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
Is there a guide how to create WPF window?

Comment: @codeDom: You don't need a guide for creating a WPF window inside a native proces.  You need to compose two operations: loading managed code inside a native process, and creating a WPF window using managed code.  Guides exist for each of these individually.

Comment: Pretty easy to find if you Bingle it. Without knowing more about your scenario, it's difficult to provide definitive guidance, but I've added a couple of other resources above that may help.

Comment: Thank you very much, my main goal is security against reflector
Do you think I'm doing right?

Comment: No ... unless you're going to precompile all your managed code into native code at build time. For this purpose, [.NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx) is most likely a better option than trying to roll your own.

Note: Windows Universal Apps are precompiled into platform-specific native code (using .NET Native) for each platform (x86, x64, ARM) when you upload your app into the store so you'll get that for free.

Comment: Also ... If you're building .NET libraries or desktop apps and (think you) want to obfuscate, 

a) consider [DotFuscator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator), 
b) how likely it is that someone's going to bother to take the time and effort to RE your assemblies? Is it worth the effort to obfuscate and how effectively will doing so protect your IP?